# MD5 not consistently generating the same encrypted data for the same password

Tags: java, security, authentication, md5

To secure my web application, I thought about encryption the password field with MD5. I used this code.

```
            byte[] bytesOfMessage;
            String  password= "123456789";
            bytesOfMessage = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
            String newPassword = thedigest.toString();
```

But in the login form when I check the password I found that the same algorithm produced different MD5 hashes. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What do you mean "the same algorithm"?  Clearly, it's a different algorithm.  But we can't tell you what the difference between two things is if you only show us one of them.  Maybe you could include the code that you use in the login form too.

Comment: it works , thanks ,Can you explain me the difference ? I can get it because i thought that it is the same thing.

Comment: You've asked what the difference is between two different things.  But you've only shown us one of the two things.  I need a crystal ball to answer this question.

Comment: MD5 doesn't encrypt anything. It generates secure message digests.

Comment: i mean the difference between thedigest.toString() and new String(thedigest)

Comment: 1. `byte[].toString()` doesn't vary according to the contents. 2. A digest is binary data. `String` is not a container for binary data. If you need to store it in a `String` you need to hex-encode it, base64-encode it, ...

Comment: If you set up an array of bytes, and try out both `theBytes.toString()` and `new String(theBytes)`, you'll see the difference very clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not calculating MD5 but SHA-1:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
```

Change it to:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
```

Second, to convert a byte array to `String`, you have 2 options: either convert it to a hex string (preferred) or to a base64 string.

Here is how you can convert `byte[]` to `String`:

[Convert from byte array to hex string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: yes that's true , but  it's a taping mistake , well i try the diffrent type of encryption and i get it work when i change thedigest.toString() to new String(thedigest)

Answer (score 1):

So the actual answer is: You have called `byte[].toString()` instead of `new String(byte[], StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

`toString` on byte arrays always works as [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).
That is, it returns text based on the class name and identity hash code.
`Object`'s implementation of `hashCode` is based on the object identity, not its contents.
Thus for different runs of the method, separate arrays are allocated, resulting in different hash codes even if the arrays end up containing the same bytes.
[`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte[]%29) returns a string based on the array's contents. It gives a result like `"[2, 1, 0, 100]"`.

`new String(byte[])` *(looks this up)* uses the default character set which may change between runs. I've used the newish Java SE 8 `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`, but `new String(thedigest, "UTF-8")` should also work, so long as I've typed "UTF-8" correctly.